# Summation of the absolute difference between every two adjacent number is maximum in a array

Tags: c

e.g for (1,2,7) , M =[1-7]+[2-7} which gives M=11
instead of calculating directly it gives 6 as [1-2]+[2-7]
someone please help me how to solve this?? i have used array to find max and min but afterwards I don't know how to proceed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long int a[100000];
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%lu",&a[i]);
    }
    int max=a[0];
    int min=a[0];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(a[i]>max){
          max=a[i];  
        }else if(a[i]<min){
            min=a[i];
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",max);
    printf("%d\n",min);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because clearly a write my code request, not a question. Please read [Ask] page first. :)

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: sourav im new at SO so sorry for the inconvieniance

Comment: No issues, please update the question as mentioned in the provided link. We'll be happy to help. :)

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long int a[100000];
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%lu",&a[i]);
    }
    int max=a[0];
    int min=a[0];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(a[i]>max){
          max=a[i];  
        }else if(a[i]<min){
            min=a[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Max=%d\n",max);
    printf("MIN=%d\n",min);

    return 0;
}

Comment: What do you actually want to solve?

Comment: please [edit] the question and add your update there.

Comment: @jboockmann actually i gave a exam today online where i unable to asnwer this question so im trying to get some help from all you people out there

Comment: sourov da code oikhane past korle error show korche

Comment: find max then summation absolute difference

Comment: sourov da please help?

Comment: @CodeRed Let me see how I can help

Comment: Which one you're actually trying to get? 12 or 11?

Comment: also how come 12 there??

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void){
    long int a[100000], max = LONG_MIN;
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%lu", &a[i]);
        if(a[i] > max)
            max = a[i];
    }
    long long int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        sum += labs(a[i] - max);
    }
    printf("%lld\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for an array given OP's "e.g for `(1,2,7), M =[1-7]+[2-7}` which gives `M=11`"

This is
`(max - a[0]) + (max - a[1]) + ... + (max - a[n-1])` -->  `n*max - sum(a[])`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int max=INT_MIN;
    int min=INT_MAX;
    long long sum = 0;
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      int a;
      if (scanf("%d",&a) != 1) {
        puts("fail");
        return -1;
      }
      if (a > max) max = a;
      if (a > min) min = a;
      sum += a;
    }
    printf("min %d\n", min);
    printf("max %d\n", max);

    printf("m %lld\n", 1LL*n*max - sum);
    return 0;
}
```